# SQL Server: Comparing a list of strings with wildcards using LIKE

Tags: sql-server, nested, wildcard, sql-like, sql-in

I'm trying to find a way to compare a character field with a few string wildcards stored in a lookup table. For example, Table A is my main table. There is a column called "Code" in Table A which I need to evaluate. I want to find all rows `WHERE Code LIKE "ABC%", "A%", or "A12%"`. These three strings are stored in a lookup table called Table B. I am trying to avoid hard-coding these wildcards at all costs. Is there a way to do something like `WHERE A.Code LIKE (SELECT * FROM B)` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like below using **INNER JOIN**:

```
SELECT TableA.* FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.Code LIKE TableB.Code + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But I stored the "%" in the strings in the lookup table. So I don't need this in my LIKE clause. But I get the idea and it works!

Comment: Storing `operator` in table is not a good idea, you should just store the values and can use the query like i provided. Don't forget to follow [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Can you tell me why it isn't a good idea to store operator in tables?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM tabA a
JOIN tabB b
  ON a.Code LIKE b.col_name;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/GMDY35830)**